# How can I pass more parameters to a custom sort() function?

Tags: javascript, parameters, sorting, optional-parameters

I have an array of objects I need to sort on a custom function. Since I want to do this several times on several object attributes, I'd like to pass the key name for the attribute dynamically into the custom sort function:

```
function compareOnOneFixedKey(a, b) {
    a = parseInt(a.oneFixedKey)
    b = parseInt(b.oneFixedKey)
    if (a < b) return -1
    if (a > b) return 1
        return 0
}
    
arrayOfObjects.sort(compareByThisKey)
```

This should become something like:

```
function compareOnKey(key, a, b) {
    a = parseInt(a[key])
    b = parseInt(b[key])
    if (a < b) return -1
    if (a > b) return 1
        return 0
}
arrayOfObjects.sort(compareOn('myKey'))
```

Can this be done in a convenient way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You would need to [partially apply](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application) the function, e.g. using [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
arrayOfObjects.sort(compareOn.bind(null, 'myKey'));
```

Or you just make `compareOn` return the actual sort function, parametrized with the arguments of the outer function (as demonstrated by the others).

Comment: Besides the method is good it still has compatibility problems.

Comment: @VisioN: …but makes so many thing easier :-) For anybody considering supporting old IEs, the linked MDN page contains a shim

Comment: @VisioN `.bind` is supported in IE9 and this requires mimimal refactoring of current code

Comment: On chrome, shim added, i cannot make this work function refacrtored as: function compareOn(a, b, key) {
        a = parseInt(a[key], 10)
        b = parseInt(b[key], 10)
        if (a < b) return -1
        if (a > b) return 1
        return 0
    }

Comment: @paolo: If you want to use partial application, the `key` argument needs to come first (as in your second snippet).

Comment: Perfectly working now! Thank you very much for such an educative solution!

Answer (score 17):

You may add a wrapper:

```
function compareOnKey(key) {
    return function(a, b) {
        a = parseInt(a[key], 10);
        b = parseInt(b[key], 10);
        if (a < b) return -1;
        if (a > b) return 1;
        return 0;
    };
}

arrayOfObjects.sort(compareOnKey("myKey"));
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, have the comparator returned from a generator which takes a param which is the key you want

```
function compareByProperty(key) {
    return function (a, b) {
        a = parseInt(a[key], 10);
        b = parseInt(b[key], 10);
        if (a < b) return -1;
        if (a > b) return 1;
        return 0;
    };
}
arrayOfObjects.sort(compareByProperty('myKey'));
```

`compareByProperty('myKey')` returns the function to do the comparing, which is then passed into `.sort`

Comment: working well, but choosen the .bind() way for its flexibility. thank you for refactoring my code with the base 10 in parseInt :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const objArr = [{
    name: 'Z',
    age: 0
  }, {
    name: 'A',
    age: 25
  }, {
    name: 'F',
    age: 5
}]
  
const sortKey = {
    name: 'name',
    age: 'age'
}

const sortArr = (arr, key) => {
    return arr.sort((a, b) => {
        return a[key] < b[key] ? -1 : a[key] > b[key] ? 1 : 0
    })
}
  
console.log("sortKey.name: ", sortArr(objArr, sortKey.name))
console.log("sortKey.age: ", sortArr(objArr, sortKey.age))
```