# Javascript access parameter inside custom sort function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I have a custom sort function defined & call it as below;

```
myArr.sort(this.sortArrayBy, key);

sortArrayBy: function(a, b) {

    let param = this.get('sortKey'); //How do I get this value here ? cannot pass it as param OR even access via 'this'

    if (a.param < b.param)
        return -1;
    if (a.param > b.param)
        return 1;
    return 0;
},
```

I want to pass an additional param inside that function. How do I get access to that class attribute ?

P.S: This code is inside my Ember controller class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [js sort() custom function how can i pass more parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491695/js-sort-custom-function-how-can-i-pass-more-parameters)

Comment: What are you expecting `this` to be a reference to?

Answer (score 2):

You can't make this `.sort()` take an extra parameter. A workaround is to create a function which wraps a custom defined sort function which *does* take the additional parameter.

---

You can define your own sort function which takes an extra parameter:

```
sortArrayBy: function(a, b, param) {
    // ... sort logic here ...
    return 0;
}
```

Then, at the point you call `myArr.sort`, you can define a wrapper to this function which only takes the expected two parameters:

```
var self = this;
var sortFunc = function(a, b) {
    return self.sortArrayBy(a, b, self.get('sortKey'));  
};
myArr.sort(sortFunc, key);
```

Comment: Thanks @testndtv -- I've changed it

Comment: Thanks a lot for that...Works like a charm now...Is it possible to customize the sort function further to support both ascending/descending based on 1 param isAscending=true/false ?

Comment: Sure -- you're free to change your internal sort function as much as you want. For example, you could multiply the result as follows: `return s * (isAscending ? 1 : -1);` where `s` is the value you would have returned normally.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a closure over the wanted sort key.

```
myArr.sort(this.sortArrayBy(key));

sortArrayBy: function (param) {
    return function(a, b) {
        if (a[param] < b[param])
            return -1;
        if (a[param] > b[param])
            return 1;
        return 0;
    };
},
```

Comment: Nina, can you fix the typo on line 5 `b.[param]` to `b[param]`. Apparently edits must be at least 6 characters. So I'm not able to make an edit.

Comment: param is not available inside the closure...so a[param] & b[param] do not work

Comment: please add some data to the question for sorting.