# Javascript Custom sort function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a custom sort function defined as below

```
sortArrayBy: function(a, b, sortKey) {
    if (a[sortKey] < b[sortKey])
        return -1;
    if (a[sortKey] > b[sortKey])
        return 1;
    return 0;
},
```

How can I update it to dynamically sort/toggle based on an additional parameter isAscending which can be true/false

So the function signature would look like

```
sortArrayBy: function(a, b, sortKey, isAscending) {

}
```

Comment: Can you please add an example of expected Input & Output?

Comment: what about the [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48517842/javascript-access-parameter-inside-custom-sort-function) without any data. it is the same question.

Answer (score 5):

Convert `isAscending` to a `1` (for ascending) or `-1` (for descending)

```
sortArrayBy: function(a, b, sortKey, isAscending) {
   return (a[sortKey] - b[sortKey]) * (isAscending ? 1 : -1);
}
```

**Demo**

```js
function sortArrayBy(arr, sortKey, isAscending) {
  return arr.sort( ( a, b ) => (a[sortKey] - b[sortKey]) * (isAscending ? 1 : -1) );
}

var arr = [
   { a : 1, b: 2 },
   { a : 4, b: 6 },
   { a : 3, b: 4 },
   { a : 12, b: 1 },
   { a : 5, b: 23 },
];

console.log( sortArrayBy( arr, "a", true ) );

console.log( sortArrayBy( arr, "a", false ) );
```

**Edit**

Including string comparison as well

```
function sortArrayBy(arr, type, sortKey, isAscending) {
  if ( type == "string" )
  {
     return arr.sort( ( a, b ) => a[sortKey].localeCompare(b[sortKey]) * (isAscending ? 1 : -1) );
  }

  return arr.sort( ( a, b ) => (a[sortKey] - b[sortKey]) * (isAscending ? 1 : -1) );
}
```

```js
function sortArrayBy(arr, type, sortKey, isAscending) {
  if ( type == "string" )
  {
     return arr.sort( ( a, b ) => a[sortKey].localeCompare(b[sortKey]) * (isAscending ? 1 : -1) );
  }
  
  return arr.sort( ( a, b ) => (a[sortKey] - b[sortKey]) * (isAscending ? 1 : -1) );
}

var arr = [
   { a : 1, b: "32" },
   { a : 4, b: "w6" },
   { a : 3, b: "s4" },
   { a : 12, b: "v1" },
   { a : 5, b: "2s3" },
];

console.log( sortArrayBy( arr, "", "a", true ) );

console.log( sortArrayBy( arr, "", "a", false ) );


console.log( sortArrayBy( arr, "string", "b", true ) );

console.log( sortArrayBy( arr, "string", "b", false ) );
```

Comment: For some reasons, returning the same data set when isAscending is 1 or -1

Comment: @testndtv Please share some sample data-sets in your question.

Comment: @testndtv I have shared a demo.

Comment: Thanks..yes, I was passing 1 or -1 from the calling function itself...But can we extend this function to sort both alpha & numeric values...I want to srt in a grid which can have values like "abc", "xyz" and also some columns can have 1,2

Comment: Sure, give it a try and post a new question if you are stuck somewhere.

Comment: @testndtv Check the updates having type based comparison.

Answer (score 1):

easy one

```
sortArrayBy: function(a, b, sortKey , isAscending) {
    if (parseFloat(a[sortKey]) < parseFloat(b[sortKey]))
        return isAscending ? -1 : 1;
    if (parseFloat(a[sortKey]) > parseFloat(b[sortKey]))
        return isAscending ? 1 : -1;
    return 0;
},
```

Comment: Thanks. Will this support both string & number data ?

Comment: Yes it should be

Comment: Does not sort the below 3 data properly "111.00", "55.00", "120.00"